# Subluminal speed when going in a circle around someone

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, speed-of-light, reference-frames, thought-experiment

Some time ago I thought about such situation:

There are two people in the room. Both have synchronized watches on their wirsts. Then the person A starts running around person B with the speed of 0.9999999999999c. Person A maintains his radial distance from person B, but his tangential speed is constantly 0.9999999999999c. We assume that both are immortal and full of energy.

How will A's time dilate with respect to B? And the size. Will it change? Well at least how should I try to calculate it by myself?

Comment: Remember, that for all paths, we have ${\dot x}_{\mu}{\dot x}^{\mu} = -1$.  You know that for a circle, the spatial part is given by $x = r \cos \omega t$ and $y = r \sin \omega t$.  This is enough to figure out the time dilation factor.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer Are you sure that it is enough to change coordinates? I heard that this question is very hard, because there's acceleration involved. This is what my physics tutor told.
And could you give me the name of the first equation (with "-1") I have never faced this.

Comment: Well, it's not changing coordinates.  It's describing the path of the circular orbit in the unaccelerated frame.

Comment: The first equation is just the condition of a timelike curve parameterized by arc length, which is the standard assumption about observers in special relativity -- everyone has a clock that belongs to their frame.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer But what about centripetal acceleration? I'm so stubborn, because my tutor said it is very hard question. And there was nothing about circular movement in my classes about special relativity.

Comment: You can measure it.  It's certainly teh case that the two observer will both agree as to who the accelerated observer is, but that doesn't change that their orbit is completely acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

In observer B's frame, we know that observer A has spatial path:

$$\begin{align}
x &= r \cos\omega \tau\\
y&= r \sin \omega \tau
\end{align}$$

Furthermore, we know that, when measuring their path according to arc length, we have:

$$-1 = -{\dot t}^{2} + {\dot x}^{2} + {\dot y}^{2} + {\dot z}^{2}$$

Therefore, we have:

$$\begin{align}
-1 &= -{\dot t}^{2} + r^{2}\omega^{2}\\
{\dot t} &= \sqrt{1 + r^{2}\omega^{2}}\\
t &= \tau \sqrt{1 + r^{2}\omega^{2}}
\end{align}$$

where $\tau$ is the clock time measured by observer A.  So, therefore, observer B sees $A$'s time slowed down by a factor of $\sqrt{1 + v^{2}}$